# I'm having trouble installing TestNG on eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0), OS-win10, java version 10.0.2

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I'm having trouble installing TestNG on eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0), OS-win10, java version 10.0.2

I get the below error. Also when I tried to access testng.org it says "Service Temporarily Unavailable". Please help. Thank you.

"HTTP Server 'Service Unavailable': http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml
HttpComponents connection error response code 503."

[Scrrenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOIF6.png)

Comment: How does `installing TestNG on eclipse` have a relation with `Selenium` tag?

Comment: I'm using TestNG as the framework in my Selenium web driver script @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a temporary ISP outage, http://testng.org is back up.

The project is alive and well, and we're busing working on the next major version.

Comment: Thank you @Cedric Beust for creating TestNG, while the site was offline I managed to install TestNG manually offline

Answer (score 2):

TestNG project is very much alive.

There was an outage on the site, which was raised with the service provider and fixed thereafter. The site is back online.

Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced same issue in latest version of Eclipse(as of today) and following is the workaround that worked for me

In **Install new Software** dialog of Eclipse enter URL http://beust.com/eclipse instead of https://beust.com/eclipse

Happy testing :-)